# Replace an element title box?

Tags: jquery, html, title

Is it possible to replace/disable the title box in an HTML element, so I could create my own with the title value in it?

If not: In case of the standard principle, is it "legal" to use an own attribute on an element to accomplish this? Or should I rather store the title value outside the element, in a JavaScript array for example?

Comment: When you say "title box", do you mean the title attribute on an element (ie <div title=''>), or the title tag in the head? After looking and thinking more, I think you mean to replace the popup/tooltip that the title attribute creates by default when you hover over the element. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry about my obscurity. Yes, I do mean the popup which is generated from the title attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script that searches for certain elements with the `title` attribute, remove the `title` attribute from said elements and replace it with custom HTML elements containing the title text that appear on hover.

There are plenty of jQuery tooltip plugins out there that do this, see for example [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip).

Answer (score 2):

```
function showTitle()
{
    var offset = $('#d').offset();
    $('#title').css('left', offset.left+'px');
    $('#title').css('top', (offset.top-10)+'px');
    $('#title').text($('#d').attr('title'));
    $('#title').show();
}
function hideTitle()
{
    $('#title').hide();
}

$('#d').attr('title', 'Changed');
$('#d').hover(showTitle, hideTitle);
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/lex_rwx/sj9B4/